# Monotonicity of Convex Conjugate Divided by Quadratic

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

I came across the following (unproved) convex analysis fact in a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-34/issue-6/Discussion--Local-Rademacher-complexities-and-oracle-inequalities-in-risk/10.1214/009053606000001037.full).

> **Fact:** Suppose $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function. Define its convex conjugate $\varphi^*(y)=\sup_{x\ge 0}[xy-\varphi(x)]$. If $x\mapsto\varphi(x)/x^2$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$, then $y\mapsto\varphi^*(y)/y^2$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.

I am able to prove this fact, under two extra assumptions: (1) $\varphi$ is differentiable, and (2) the supremum in $\varphi^*$ is attained by a unique $x>0$. However, I do not know how to extend this proof to the general case.

**My proof:** Let $f(x)=\varphi(x)/x^2$, then $f'(x)=\left[x\varphi'(x) - 2\varphi(x)\right]/x^3\ge 0$ for all $x>0$. Let $g(y) = \varphi^*(y)/y^2$. Fix $y>0$, and assume that $\varphi^*(y)=zy-\varphi(z)$ for a unique $z > 0$. By [Danskin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danskin%27s_theorem), $(\varphi^*)'(y)=z$, hence $y=\varphi'(z)$. Therefore,
$$
g'(y) = \frac{zy-2\varphi^*(y)}{y^3} = \frac{2\varphi(z) - zy}{y^3} = \frac{2\varphi(z) - z\varphi'(z)}{y^3} = -\frac{z^3}{y^3}f'(z)\le 0.
$$

**My questions:** Could anyone give a general proof of this fact (without my assumptions) and the intuition behind? Moreover, does this result have a more general form, e.g., does it extend to $x\mapsto\varphi(x)/x^p$ for a general power $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Examples) that the convex conjugate of $x^p$ on $(0, \infty)$ is $y^q$, where $p, q$ are conjugate exponents, i.e. $1/p + 1/q = 1$. This suggests the following generalization:

> Let $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be a convex function and $p, q > 1$ be conjugate exponents. If $\phi(x)/x^p$ is increasing on $(0, \infty)$ then $\varphi^*(y)/y^q$ is decreasing on $(0, \infty)$.

This is indeed true and can be proven using only the definition of the complex conjugate.

For $0 < y_1 < y_2$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\varphi^*(y_1)}{y_1^q} &= \frac{1}{y_1^q}\sup \left\{ x_1y_1 - \varphi(x_1) : x_1 \ge 0\right\} \\
&= \sup \left\{ \frac{x_1}{y_1^{q-1}} - \frac{1}{y_1^q}\varphi(x_1) : x_1 \ge 0 \right\} \\
&= \sup \left\{ \frac{x_2}{y_2^{q-1}} - \frac{1}{y_1^{q}}\varphi\left(\frac{y_1^{q-1}}{y_2^{q-1}}x_2\right) : x_2 \ge 0 \right\} 
\end{align}
$$
with the substitution $x_1 = x_2 y_1^{q-1}/y_2^{q-1}$.

$\phi(x)/x^p$ is increasing and $x_2 y_1^{q-1} /y_2^{q-1} \le x_2$, therefore is
$$
\varphi\left(\frac{y_1^{q-1}}{y_2^{q-1}}x_2\right) \le \left(\frac{y_1^{q-1}}{y_2^{q-1}}\right)^p\varphi(x_2) 
= \frac{y_1^{q}}{y_2^{q}}\varphi(x_2)\, .
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{\varphi^*(y_1)}{y_1^q} \ge  \sup \left\{ \frac{x_2}{y_2^{q-1}} - \frac{1}{y_2^q}\varphi\left(x_2\right) : x_2 \ge 0 \right\} 
= \frac{\varphi^*(y_2)}{y_2^q} \, .
$$